# JQuery each seems to run for every match, but this returns only the first element every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking for solutions for this for hours, **I am not using the same ID multiple times**, though it seems like the only explaination...

The graphs are defined in html like this...

```
<div class="graph v graphcpuusage"></div>
<!--some other stuff-->
<div class="graph v graphcpuusage"></div>
```

I'm filling graphs with bars using...

```
for(i=0;i<25;i++){
    $('.graph.v').append('<div class="bar"></div>');
}
```

This is the code that should change the height of each bar in a specific graph...

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    cyclegraph('.graphcpuusage',parseInt(data.cpu_usage));
}, 5000);

function cyclegraph(graph,newvalue){
    var val, mode, newval;
    $(graph).each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('h')){ //graph is horisontal, so change width
            mode='width';
        }else{ //graph is vertical, so change height, which is default
            mode='height';
        }
        newval=newvalue;
        $(this).find('.bar:not(:first-child)').each(function(index,domObject){
            val=$(this).css(mode);
            $(this).css(mode,newvalue.toString()+'%');
            newvalue=val;
        });
    });
}
```

Which is supposed to iterate through all matching graphs, which then iterates through all bars setting their height to the prior. However, a `console.log()` confirms that the code is running 48 times over 2 graphs, as expected, but only the height of the first .bar is being changed.

I've used different variations of this code with `:nth-child('+index.string()+')` and different .each statements along with different versions of JQuery, but all result in the same output. It seems that both `.each()` statements are having the same issue.

Comment: To better understand your problem, could you include your html code as well a run-able code, how about JsFiddle? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you

Comment: @JackBashford done.

Comment: @HouyNarun done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

The problem is when you call `val = $(this).css(mode)`, if it already has a value set, it will return it in px, so val will equal the string `"0px"` for example, not a number. Then, later on, on the line `newvalue = val`, `newvalue` will get set to `0px`. Then, next loop, you try to set `$(this).css(mode,newvalue.toString()+'%');`, which will try to set it to `0px%` for example.

To fix it, I did the following:

```
$(this).find('.bar:not(:first-child)').each(function(index,domObject){
    val = ($(this).data('size')) ? $(this).data('size') : 0;
    $(this).css(mode,newvalue.toString()+'%').data('size', newvalue);
    newvalue = val;
});
```

This makes sure the size is always stored as a number, not text, using jQuery's .data() method.

I tested this on my machine and it worked. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, I was always under the assumption that `.css` reads the literal value defined in the inline style, I suppose that means that `.css` reads the computed value and writes the literal value in a style tag.